# Making migrations for hasura container and running console

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, hasura

I want to make a **developer offline space** to develop my database with **hasura**

I know the existence of the container with the tag cli-migrations, but the command:

> hasura-cli console

doesn't work for accessing outside of the container.

My configuration for the docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  hasura:
    environment:
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://[some pass]:[some user]@db:5432/[some db]
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=false
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-rc.1.cli-migrations
    container_name: hasura
    volumes:
      - ./hasura-migrations:/hasura-migrations
    networks:
      - hasura-db
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
      - "8082:8081"
    restart: always
    command: hasura-cli console --console-port 8081 --no-browser
  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[some user]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[some pass]
      - POSTGRES_DB=[some db]
    image: postgres:11.4-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - hasura-db

networks:
  hasura-db:
```

There is a [Pull request](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/pull/1780) in the hasura graphql project for this issue, but is not merged.

I'm looking for a workaround for this pull request now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found a workaround for this!**

If I install **hasura cli** in my machine and use

> hasura console --console-port 8080 --endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8081

I can connect to the hasura api and run a console locally.

this is my updated *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  hasura:
    environment:
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://[some pass]:[some user]@db:5432/[some db]
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=false
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-rc.1.cli-migrations
    container_name: hasura
    volumes:
      - ./hasura-migrations:/hasura-migrations
    networks:
      - hasura-db
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    restart: always
  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[some user]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[some pass]
      - POSTGRES_DB=[some db]
    image: postgres:11.4-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - hasura-db

networks:
  hasura-db:
```